# How to use image database file created using arcoreimg tool

Tags: android, arcore

I got some list of images . Instead of loading images at runtime in ARCore Augmented images , I created myImges.imgdb database at compile time. How to use the already created db in the code. I see creating image database at runtime in google ARCore documentation ,but how to use already compiled and existing .imgdb.
Can anyone help regarding this. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [ARCore SDK examples](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/augmented_image_java/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/core/examples/java/augmentedimage/AugmentedImageActivity.java#L371). They provide a sample of loading a precompiled imgdb file at runtime.

Place your `.imgdb` file in your project's assets folder, then do something like:

```
    // Assuming this is defined within an Activity class.
    private boolean setupAugmentedImageDatabase(Session session, Config config) {
      AugmentedImageDatabase augmentedImageDatabase = new AugmentedImageDatabase(session);
      try (InputStream is = getAssets().open("sample_database.imgdb")) {
        augmentedImageDatabase = AugmentedImageDatabase.deserialize(session, is);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IO exception loading augmented image database.", e);
        return false;
      }
    }

    config.setAugmentedImageDatabase(augmentedImageDatabase);
    return true;
  }
```